# How to determine the length (in pixels) of a string being rendered on a web page?

Tags: php, html, svg

If I know the font size (12) and the font family (calibri), is there a way to determine the length (in pixels) a given string will take after it will be rendered? I am absolutely certain about the font and size. Are there any lookup tables for this purpose to determine the length in PHP code itself? I am writing a PHP script to dynamically generate an SVG image which contains various boxes filled with data pulled out of a DB. The problem is that I need to manually wrap the text around and increase the size of the box if the string is big.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the PHP function [`imagettfbbox`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) to get the size of the bounding box for the given string.

On the other hand you *can* use also [javascript to manipulate SVG images](http://www.carto.net/svg/manipulating_svg_with_dom_ecmascript/) in case you would like to handle it on the client side. That way it wouldn't even matter if the client had the specified font or not...

Comment: that was the function i was thinking of when I gave my answer ... my memory isn't as good as it used to be ...

Answer (score 19):

You could use **PHP GD** to render out the string as a image and get the size of the resulting image.

If you use this, it should work:

```
   list($left,, $right) = imageftbbox( 12, 0, "arial.ttf", "Hello World");

   $width = $right - $left;
```

Comment: It seems that Crimson is rendering the string as an image, but the question is what size to make the image so that the string will fit correctly. Can that be done with the GD library? I didn't think there was a word wrap option with GD.

Comment: phalacee, I am not able to find a way in GD to determine the string width. It seems that I must call imagecreate() with image width and height params before a string can be written to it thus making the excercise a futile round trip :(

Comment: @ Crimson, even using imageftbbox() ??? 

if you use:
list($left,, $right) = imageftbbox( 12, 0, arial.ttf, "Hello World");

$width = $right - $left;

it should work ...

Comment: There is a typo in `imageftbbox`

Answer (score 5):

Your title and actual post seem to say slightly different things. I'm guessing what you're really asking is whether it's possible to determine the width in pixels of text rendered on a web page **in your PHP code** (prior to web page being rendered).

If so, the answer is "NO". Said font may not be available on user's computer; s/he may have custom stylesheet applied; use large font sizes; etc...

What you **can** do is determine that width using javascript *after* the page is rendered (obviously, you can do that in some other page as well and hope nothing changes till then) and submit that back to PHP. With some clever AJAX-ing you can even do this on the same page.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript) for details on how to do this in javascript.

Comment: Please see my edit. +1 for the link but it does not solve my purpose :(

Comment: @ChssPly76 - I disagree. Crimson is using PHP to generate an image. That is done on the server side, so the font will definitely be available.

Comment: @Abinadi - Crimson is asking how many pixels will that string take when rendered **in browser**, not in the image he's rendering. Or, at least, that's the way I understood it.

Comment: @Crimson - if you're truly **absolutely** certain that said string will be rendered using that font / size (which I suppose is possible if you have complete control over the end environment - specific browser / OS / fonts) you can actually use GD to find that out as suggested by `phalacee`

Comment: Actually, it is a little bit of both as I am using the SVG definition for an image - the image is not a bitmap. Thus, it is the browser's problem to find the correct font but let's say that the font is definitely available. How do we find the width now? How can I retrieve the pixel width of each glyph in the font and sum?

Comment: @Crimson - take a look at 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php for example. Assuming you have the font file available on your server, this should do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery,

```
$("text").each(function(){alert(this.innerHTML+" is "+$(this).width()+" pixels.");});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to determine the string length of text, using PHP's Build-In-Fonts (e.g. if you are using imagestring()), you can use:

```
imagefontwidth()


$text = "Your text here"
$fontSize = 5;

$textLength = imagefontwidth($fontSize) * strlen($text);
```

If you do not use the Build-In-Fonts, use imagettfbbox(), like mentioned above.