# Any way to calculate the pixel length of a string?

Tags: php, string, image, gd

I'm using the GD library for PHP, and using functions like imagestring() and imagestringup() to add text to pictures.  I am using the built-in fonts with latin2 encoding.  Is there a way, with a given string, to calculate the length (in pixels) of the string?

I want to calculate the length in pixels of the strings because the strings are variable and I want to make sure the string doesn't overflow the area I want to put it in.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641756/how-to-determine-the-length-in-pixels-of-a-string-being-rendered-on-a-web-page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

imagettfbbox() does that:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

Comment: But this doesn't work with the built-in fonts, it needs a font file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the string length of text, using PHP's Build-In-Fonts (e.g. if you are using imagestring()), you can use:

```
imagefontwidth()


$text = "Your text here"
$fontSize = 5;

$textLength = imagefontwidth($fontSize) * strlen($text);
```

If you do not use the Build-In-Fonts, use imagettfbbox(), like mentioned above.