# How to get string's pixel length in PHP?

Tags: php

There is a string , say `$x = "Poste : ";`
How to get $x's pixel length ? That is how many pixels does $x occupy ?

Comment: Depends on font, bold, italic, etc

Comment: There's not enough info.  How is it printed?  In what font: type face, size, weight, decoration, character spacing, etc.

Comment: Also, if I am using a 200% zoom, then?

Comment: As long as you output this string to a browser, only the browser knows how the text gets displayed. PHP knows nothing about it unless you produce some graphics via PHP.

Comment: makes little sense, may as well ask how much it will weight

Comment: Once you know all the font details, you can then use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641756/how-to-determine-the-length-in-pixels-of-a-string-being-rendered-on-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not exist. Indeed, each character in its own width depending on the font, the font size, style (bold, italic, normal, etc..).

A parade is to use a fixed-width font like Courier New style such as each character to the same width ;)