# How to get the width of a string in php?

Tags: php

For example:

the width of "English" = 7

the width of "中文" = 4

Is there a way to get the "width" of a string?

*Update:*

I know that in the UTF-8 encoding,

```
strlen("English") = 7
strlen("中文") = 6 

mb_strlen("English") = 7
mb_strlen("中文") = 2
```

I want the result of some function("中文") to be 4 .  You see, the **width** of these two strings are equal:

```
word
中文
```

Comment: You want string *length*. [`mb_strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) and [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

Comment: `strlen()` returns the number of characters, he's looking for the width of the characters, which I doubt is possible

Comment: Can you explain what "width" means? Character count, byte count, number of pixels in a specific font?

Comment: What are criteria to determine that `中文`'s width is 4?

Comment: Looking at the sample you just posted, on my tablet, in that font, the two strings are not equal width.

Comment: Sorry for the question (I obviously don't know anything about ideographs) but... is that visual width something fixed or it depends on the font?

Comment: I don't see how those 2 strings are equal. If you mean that each character of the language you're using is equal to 2 characters of latin - then simply mb_strlen * 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the length (in pixels) of a string being rendered on a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641756/how-to-determine-the-length-in-pixels-of-a-string-being-rendered-on-a-web-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After browsing all the functions starting with mb_ , I found this. It is exactly what I was looking for:

`mb_strwidth()`

> It Returns the width of a string, where halfwidth characters
> count as 1, and fullwidth characters count as 2.

https://www.php.net/mb_strwidth

Comment: Well, I learned something today so thank you.